# Gauss-Newton method, where did sigma inverse come from?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares, jacobian

I'm studying the Gauss-Newton Method from "slambook-en" chapter 5 on optimization (the books is made free online by the author in case you need to see it). I've attached a picture of the example the author is using to elaborate the method. My doubt is with the sudden appearance of the sigma inverse in the final formulation. I understand how the general Gauss Newton method works out to approximate the hessian matrix, but I'm struggling to understand the sigma inverse. It is of course (or at least I think) related to the 'w' in page 1 that I have attached which is used to simulate the gaussian noise, but that is the extent to which I understand it. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Page 1]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am familiar with least squares method(s) but here, like you, I am surprized by the uprising of this $\sigma^2$ coming out of nowhere (no doubt it is correct but usually we do least squares without multiplying LHS and RHS by a same number ; hopefully, this unique $\sigma^2$ is bound to become three different $\sigma_k^2$s) ; please include the next page in order that the promised code brings some light...

Comment: @JeanMarie I have attached the pictures of the code in the post it self. I'm not sure what you mean about the sigma becoming three different ones, but from the code, they are only referring to one sigma. Also, can we simply just factor out the sigma and cancel them out on both sides of the equation since they are the same without changing the result?

Comment: Yes, it is what I said : it is an exact relationship because we can cancel the $\sigma^2$, but what is then the interest to introduce it ???

Comment: I have examined the code : solving $Hx=b$ (line 48), after (line 42 and 43) having multiplied $H$ and $b$ by $\sigma^2$ gives the same solution as if we hadn't multiplied by $\sigma^2$ ...   ; besides, giving "talkative" pieces of code like this doesn't improve the understanding of the methods. The least one can say is that this online book is strange

Comment: "talkative" code : an example, what is the point to write instructions 3,4,6,7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no point in including the $(\sigma^2)^{-1}$.

However, it would make sense, and constitute [Weighted least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares) if $\sigma^2$ were not the same across all data points ("equations"), i.e., $\sigma^2_i$, with formulas involving $(\sigma^2_i)^{-1}$.

More generally, $\Sigma^{-1}$ would be used ([Generalized least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares))if the covariance among the data points were $\Sigma$. Use of $(\sigma^2_i)^{-1}$ corresponds to the special case in which the covariance matrix, and hence its inverse, being diagonal.